# Find and highlight duplicate entries in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I want to find duplicate rows and highlight every duplicate row *with unique content* separately.

As an example:

Row 1 - 'transaction $44.20'

Row 25 - 'transaction $44.20'

Row 31 - 'transaction $57.40'

Row 46 - 'transaction $57.40'

Row 54 - 'transaction $57.40'

Row 156 - 'transaction $15.90'

Row 197 - 'transaction $15.90'

As you see there are three sets of duplications - rows 1 and 25, rows 31, 46 and 54 and rows 156 and 197 while each duplicate content is unique.

I want to find and highlight all these unique, yet duplicate entries sets, each set with separate color. So rows 1,25 - one color, rows 31,46,54 - another, rows 156,197 - third and so on.

Excel's own Conditional Formatting->Highlight Cell Rules->Find Duplicates will highlight all of them with the same color. This is not what I want.

Ideas?

Comment: Solution 1: VBA / Solution 2: helper column and then conditionally format rows based on the helper column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd have a go at this and brush up my VBA skills a bit, although it's probably been done before.

The idea is that I'm using a dictionary to store the different transaction amounts as keys. If a key is found for a second time, then I know it's a duplicate and can highlight both the original value and the dup.

I've chosen to define a class Dictionary Entry that stores the location of the first instance of the 'key', plus a Boolean flag that tells me if it has already occurred more than once before (in which case I don't need to change the colour but will just retrieve the existing colour).

```
Public FirstInstance As Long, Dup As Boolean
```

Since there are only 56 colours in the predefined colour set, this will eventually run out of colours so I have set it to repeat the colour set if this happens, but things would get pretty confusing before then IMO

```
Sub HighlightDups()
Dim MyDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary
Set MyDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim MyDictionaryEntry As DictionaryEntry
Dim MyColour, palette As Integer
Dim I, LastRow As Long
Dim contents As Single
palette = 2

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With MyDictionary
For i = 1 To LastRow
    contents = Cells(i, 1)
    If Not .Exists(contents) Then
        ' New key - create entry
        Set MyDictionaryEntry = New DictionaryEntry
        MyDictionaryEntry.FirstInstance = i
        .Add contents, MyDictionaryEntry
    Else
        If Not .Item(contents).Dup Then
            ' Dup not previously found - set new colour
            palette = palette + 1
            If palette > 56 Then palette = 2
            .Item(contents).Dup = True
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = palette
            Cells(.Item(contents).FirstInstance, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = palette

        Else
            'Dup already found - retrieve previous colour
            MyColour = Cells(.Item(contents).FirstInstance, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = MyColour
        End If
    End If
Next i
End With

End Sub
```

You may have to Google how to add a class and a dictionary in order to make this work - it's fairly straightforward though.

[image]